# Plotting a set of functions using a 'violin-plot' style plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say I want to visualize the functions `f[n] = e^{-(x-n)^2}/n` for `n=1...10`.   Notice that these are not probability distributions.

(not actually the plot I want to do, but close enough).

I'd like to demonstrate it with something like a violin-plot (https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/violinplot.html) where for each `n` I have a vertical line and I plot the function on both sides of the vertical line.

But violin plots seem to only be used for showing the locations of a sample of data.  So all the tools for it require me to give it a data set.  The data I want to plot isn't of that type - it's an actual known function.

[if you want more context this is related to an earlier question of mine - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403359/visualizing-2d-data-when-one-dimension-is-discrete-and-the-other-continuous].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad, so maybe this is not actually what you're looking for. But as I understand it, you just want to plot your function at position `f(x,n)` at different positions `n` and have `x` on the vertical axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x, n: np.exp(-(x-n)**2)/n

x = np.linspace(-2,12,101)
ns = np.arange(1,11)

for n in ns:
    plt.fill_betweenx(x, -f(x,n)+n, f(x,n)+n, color="C0", alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("x")
plt.xticks(ns)        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({n: [np.exp(-(x-n)**2)/n  for x in np.arange(-1,1,0.1)] for n in range(1,11)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,10))
ax.violinplot(df.T)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]